# ReactJs ref.current always null

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

so im trying to trigger `child` function from its parrent using `ref`.

this is my parrent class

```
class EmailVerification extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchFeedbackOptionList();
        this.emailVerification = React.createRef();
    }

    doSubmitQuisioner() {
        console.log('doSubmitQuisioner', this.emailVerification);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <EmailVerificationComponent
                feedbackOptionList={this.props.feedbackOptionList}
                doSubmitQuisioner={() => this.doSubmitQuisioner()}
                ref={this.emailVerification}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('emailVerification', state);
    return {
        feedbackOptionList: state.fetchFeedbackOptionListReducer.feedbackOptionList
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchFeedbackOptionList,
    fetchSubmitFeedback
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EmailVerification);
```

but when i try to console.log `this.emailVerification` by trigerring `doSubmitQuisioner` from the `children`, its always return `{current: null}`.

this is my `react` and `react-dom` version

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
```

Comment: I'd say you need to bind your `doSubmitQuisioner()` like so `this.doSubmitQuisioner = this.doSubmitQuisioner.bind(this)` in the constructor or define it as a function.

Comment: i already try ur suggestion, its still return me `{current : null}`, im also try to make `doSubmitQuisioner = () => {}` its still return me `null`. :(